# How can I calculate time difference for different sections with columns that have the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, time

I want to calculate the time difference in each session for the same URLs, I am not sure how should I do that.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LogTime': ['2018-12-12 11:18:37.782000+00:00 ', '2018-12-12 11:20:35.782000+00:00', '2018-12-12 11:21:39.782000+00:00','2018-12-12 11:22:39.782000+00:00', '2018-12-12 11:22:40.782000+00:00', '2018-12-12 11:23:40.782000+00:00'],
       'Session': ['a','a','b','c','c','c'],
       'URL': ['/','/','/page','/new','/new','/']
      })
```

It should calculate the time difference between the same URL in the same section. If the Url only appear once,the time difference is will be set to 1 minute.

The Expected output is:
time = pd.DataFrame({'Session': ['a','b','c','c'], 'URL': ['/','/page','/new', '/'] 'Duration': ['time1','time2', 'time3','time4']})

Comment: Please show your expected output as text [edit]ed into your question.

Comment: First get the datetime instance using `datetime.strptime("2018-12-12 11:18:37.782000+00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")` then you can basically apply the `-` operator between them. This is a partial answer as I can't fully understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: For the output, I would expect: time = pd.DataFrame({'Session': ['a','b','c','c'],
                     'URL': ['/','/page','/new', '/']
                    'Duration': ['time1','time2', 'time3','time4']})

Answer (score 0):

Fairly clunky but:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LogTime': ['2018-12-12 11:18:37.782000+00:00 ', '2018-12-12 11:20:35.782000+00:00', '2018-12-12 11:21:39.782000+00:00','2018-12-12 11:22:39.782000+00:00', '2018-12-12 11:22:40.782000+00:00', '2018-12-12 11:23:40.782000+00:00'],
   'Session': ['a','a','b','c','c','c'],
   'URL': ['/','/','/page','/new','/new','/']
  })

df['LogTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LogTime'])

times = []
ur = []

for n, g in df.groupby('URL'):

    if len(g) == 1:
        times.append(pd.Timedelta(minutes = 1))
        ur.append(n)
    else:
        times.append(g.LogTime.max() - g.LogTime.min())
        ur.append(n)

df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'TimeDiff':times, 'URL':ur}), on='URL')
df
```

Which basically groups together identical URLS, then adds the difference between the minimum and maximum time in the LogTime columns, per group, unless there is only one entry, where the loop will return 1 minute.

Then it merges on the original df.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I just have one question, how I modify it to have the code group by session as well? I want to calculate the time duration of different URL in each session. Somehow, when I add criterion df.groupby(['URL','Session'), it does not seem to work.